# Azure Function - What version of the ARM Template APIs support "Dynamic" YI tier sku for Linux?

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-functions

**Background Information**

I have function app with 3 different functions inside.  I also have written a powershell script that deploys these functions upstream to Azure portal.  It basically just calls this function:

```
func azure functionapp publish $FUNCTION_APP.name --publish-local-settings -i --overwrite-settings -y
```

Whenever I run the powershell script, I see the following error message:

> Setting PExtStorageQueue = ****
> Syncing triggers...
> Syncing triggers...
> Syncing triggers...
> Syncing triggers...
> Syncing triggers...
> Syncing triggers...
> Error calling sync triggers (BadRequest). Request ID = 'b4a22cd4-5c5b-4b2b-a9d4-537cb9cdf96a'.

The functions do end up being deployed and I can trigger them. But none of them have URLs in the "Get URL" option.

**What I've checked so far**

1. Based on other posts, it seems that enabling slots might cause issues so I've verified that I DO NOT have slots enabled.

[image]

2. Container OS.  I'm using Linux containers.  The version of the Linux container is dotnet|3.1 for the function app.  I've also tried to change it to "dotnetcore|6.0" per this article: https://medium.com/medialesson/solved-the-parameter-linuxfxversion-has-an-invalid-value-net6-linux-533c759456cd.  But that just causes the script to die with the following error when I use dotnetcore:

   Line |
   38 |  New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName $currentEnv.AZ_RESOU …
   |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   | 3:05:27 PM - The deployment 'myresourcegroupname-resources' failed with error(s). Showing 1 out of 1 error(s). Status Message: The parameter LinuxFxVersion has an invalid value. (Code: BadRequest)
   | - The parameter LinuxFxVersion has an invalid value. (Code:)  -  (Code:BadRequest)  -  (Code:)   CorrelationId: 6f7e4efb-a0b9-46c1-9d4a-df8f6c8d155e

**ARM Template for App Plan**

Here's the section in the template for the app service plan:

```
{
  "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
  "apiVersion": "2020-06-01",
  "name": "[variables('appServicePlanPortalName')]",
  "location": "[parameters('location')]",
  "sku": {
    "name": "Y1",
    "tier": "Dynamic",
    "size": "Y1",
    "family": "Y",
    "capacity": 0
  },
  "kind": "functionapp,linux",
  "properties": {
    "name": "[variables('appServicePlanPortalName')]",
    "reserved": true,
    "computeMode": "Dynamic"
  }
},
```

**ARM Template for the Function App**

And here's a snippet from the ARM template showing you what I'm doing for the function app itself:

```
   {
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
      "apiVersion": "2020-06-01",
      "name": "[parameters('functionAppName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "kind": "functionapp,linux",
      "identity": {
        "type": "UserAssigned",
        "userAssignedIdentities": {
          "[resourceId('Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities', variables('identityName'))]": {}
        }
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('appServicePlanPortalName'))]",
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities', variables('identityName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "reserved": true,
        "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('appServicePlanPortalName'))]",
        "siteConfig": {
          "linuxFxVersion": "dotnet|3.1",
          "appSettings": [
            {
              "name": "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY",
              "value": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Insights/components', variables('appInsightsName')), '2015-05-01').InstrumentationKey]"
            },
            {
              "name": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
              "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=', parameters('storageAccountName'), ';EndpointSuffix=', environment().suffixes.storage, ';AccountKey=',listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageAccountName')), '2019-06-01').keys[0].value)]"
            },
            {
              "name": "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION",
              "value": "~4"
            },
        {
          "name": "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME",
          "value": "dotnet"
        }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT 1**

In case it helps, I've been testing these changes to the ARM template: (git diff showing you what's been changed)

```
--- a/arm_templates/myresourcegroup-resources.json
+++ b/arm_templates/myresourcegroup-resources.json
@@ -168,17 +168,13 @@
       "name": "[variables('appServicePlanPortalName')]",
       "location": "[parameters('location')]",
       "sku": {
-        "name": "Y1",
-        "tier": "Dynamic",
-        "size": "Y1",
-        "family": "Y",
-        "capacity": 0
+        "tier": "Standard",
+        "name": "S1"
       },
       "kind": "functionapp,linux",
       "properties": {
         "name": "[variables('appServicePlanPortalName')]",
-        "reserved": true,
-        "computeMode": "Dynamic"
+        "reserved": true
       }
     },
     {
@@ -201,7 +197,7 @@
         "reserved": true,
         "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('appServicePlanPortalName'))]",
         "siteConfig": {
-          "linuxFxVersion": "dotnet|3.1",
+          "linuxFxVersion": "DOTNETCORE|6.0",
           "appSettings": [
             {
               "name": "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY",
```

It takes a super long time to publish but it eventually finishes.
It isn't able to list all my functions though, but I think I'm ok with that.  This is what I see in the powershell script window:

```
Getting site publishing info...
Creating archive for current directory...
Uploading 13 MB [#################################################################################]
Upload completed successfully.
Deployment completed successfully.
App setting AzureWebJobsStorage is different between azure and local.settings.json
Overwriting setting in azure with local value because '--overwrite-settings [-y]' was specified.
Setting FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME = ****
Setting PExtStorageTableName = ****
Setting PExtStorageQueue = ****
Functions in myresourcegroup-6z2ybl3tvqf6y-app:

PS C:\Users\me\src\azureTestDeploy>
```

But now I have URLs defined in the upstream functions!
Woot woot!
I'm going to revert each line again to try to narrow it down to the specific ARM change that solved the issue.
I'm guessing it'll be some combination, including the DOTNETCORE|6.0 change.

**EDIT 2**

I've been trying to play around with the different versions of the APIs to see how I can define a dynamic application service plan (Y1).
but I can't seem to get it working.  I know our subscription supports Y1 in eastus for Windows.  But I can't seem to get it working for Linux.
Anytime I use dynamic it gives me an error saying "The parameter LinuxFxVersion has an invalid value. (Code: BadRequest)"

Comment: have you tried to create it from UI and then, once successful, Export Template from main menu of the resource(s). There should you find a proper setup for your Funcapp to use later in your ARMs or in yuor local settings?

Comment: yeah ... that's what I ended up doing yesterday.  It seems S1 is only option for linux function apps ... at least in our case.